# How can I use ASP.NET TreeView to display informations

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I´m trying to use the ASP.NET TreeView control to display informations like some sites do. For example:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/ClientSideTreeView.aspx

The site of the link above have some code snippets that can be collapsed or expandend, showing a rectangle with the code snippets.

The first question is: Is this a TreeView control?

If positive how can I do that? Otherwise, what is this control?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a TreeView control. (Like it says "TreeView control from Microsoft with C# and ASP.NET")

More information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms529261.aspx
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/controls/article.php/c12285